# How to manually register a user in Drupal 6.x?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

The website has a normal registration form which allows users to register and the likes.

I have created a new custom form in which I am capturing the username/password etc. How do I manually register the user in Drupal system?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the answer you want, but you'd save yourself a lot of trouble by using hook_form_alter to change the current registration form:

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6

Answer (score 3):

Check out hook_user and user_save().

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_save/6

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on Kevin's suggestion of hook_user and user_save here, the code might look something like:

```
// store user name
$user_name = "user123";

// store user email
$email = "user123@gmail.com";

// set up the user fields, use user_password function for 8 character password
$fields = array(
  'name' => $user_name,
  'mail' => $email,
  'pass' => user_password(8),
  'status' => 1,
);

// give new user roles if needed, as shown below
$fields['roles'] = array('new_role');

// pass the fields to user_save() and leave first param empty to create new user
$account = user_save('', $fields);
```